# Laptop won't sleep with 2nd hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sleep, hibernate, hp-elitebook

I have installed a 2nd hard drive into my laptop and now Windows 7 refuses to shutdown all or sleep all the way.

The screen goes black and the computer's fan just stays spinning and it never enters sleep or hibernate mode.

I have checked the sleep settings and they appear to be just fine.  Additionally everything works just fine as long as leave the cdrom in instead of the hard drive.

I own an elitebook 8460p and I am replacing the cdrom with a 3.5 in sata hard drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like something about the drive caddy or its drivers is interfering with the power down process. Is there any way you can test a different caddy?

Comment: @Karan Thank you for the response.  I tested a different drive caddy and same issue, seems to be something with the drivers.  I ended up just using the large of the 2 drivers and leaving out the second drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up and decided there is no possible way to get to this to work feasibly in my experience.  Either my caddy was bad or the software needed a driver because I eventually just gave up.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on a Thinkpad with Windows 10. Posting this as it was high in Google search when I was looking for a solution.
Disabling fast startup seems to have fixed it. I have done several successful hibernates shutdowns and sleeps without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I has had a very similar problem with HP Elitebook 8460p, win7 prof. Quad core, for a long while. Today I had time to trouble shoot it. It is the caddy. My windows and HP drivers are regularly updated. I had used a 5200rpm 1TB Samsung drive earlier (at that time I suspected it may be the drive causing the problem) and several months ago I replaced that with a 7200rpm HGST drive but this issue remained the same (then I suspected it may be HP HW/Drivers). Today I found that if the 2nd drive is connected to eSATA (directly or still in caddy - I have both kind of cables) then no  problems with hibernate/shutdown occur and if the Caddy is inserted in the bay, even empty caddy, then the problem comes back. While waiting in between reboots and searching on my other LT I found this post. I wish I had found it earlier. It might have saved me parts of my troubleshooting process. I hope it helps to others.